# Can't get JUnit working with my @Autowired repository and MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to write a JUnit test on my Repository, which I want to be autowired within my application. I have the repository + test class + XML + error message below. Basically I think the application XML config is incomplete but I'm stuck at the moment on what I need to add... anyone have any idea? Thanks.

```
package org.jswiki.persistence;

@Repository
public class JSWikiRepository {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public JSWikiRepository() {

    }

    public List<JSWikiItem> getAll() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(JSWikiItem.class);
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
package org.jswiki;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"*/conf-mongodb.xml"})
public class MongoTest {

    @Autowired
    private JSWikiRepository jsRep;

    @Test
    public void canCreateNewRecord() {

        List<JSWikiItem> listWiki = jsRep.getAll();

        //for(JSWikiItem i : listWiki) {
        //  System.out.println(i.getTitle());
        //}

        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

This is my XML

```
   <!-- Activate annotation configured components -->
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <!-- Scan components for annotations within the configured package -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="org.jswiki.controller" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="org.jswiki.domain" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="org.jswiki.persistencer" />

   <!-- Define the MongoTemplate which handles connectivity with MongoDB -->
   <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
     <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
     <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="jswiki"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
   <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
     <property name="host" value="178.62.218.109"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Start of the error

```
09:52:36.520 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'org.jswiki.MongoTest': AutowiredFieldElement for private org.jswiki.persistence.JSWikiRepository org.jswiki.MongoTest.jsRep
09:52:36.527 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@39c0f4a] to prepare test instance [org.jswiki.MongoTest@1ce92674]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.jswiki.MongoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.jswiki.persistence.JSWikiRepository org.jswiki.MongoTest.jsRep; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.jswiki.persistence.JSWikiRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: your location `"*/conf-mongodb.xml` looks strange for me - did the autowiring of other beans from this configuration file work?

Comment: Autowiring works for the rest of the application, just not in the unit testing. When I wrote something like /resources/spring/conf-mongodb.xml then the xml file was not found, this was the only string to get it working. But it may still be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in 'base-package="org.jswiki.**persistencer**', while the package of JSWikiRepository is **org.jswiki.persistence**.

Comment: Oops, very stupid, but if I fix it it still doesn't work. Spelling mistake was there because I was trying different stuff.

Comment: Does it give the same error? If yes, just as an experiment, try explicitly declaring JSWikiRepository in your .xml file (and removing the @Repository annotation from this class). What happens then?